# C# TabControl TabPage passing events

Tags: c#, events, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am working with a TabControl and attaching TabPages to the TabControl, but am having a problem making one of the TabPages respond to an event. It makes me think that I am missing something about the relationship between these classes, so would appreciate some help. I want to add a number of TabPage objects to TabControl, and for one of them (the first one added), I want to send it an event to make it do something.

Here is the basic code:

```
/* tabControl is a TabControl object, and 
tabNames is a string array */

bool first = true;
foreach (string tabName in tabNames)
{
    TabPage tabPage = CreateTabPage(tabName);
    tabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage);
    if (first)
    {
        methodTabPage.Select();
        first = false;
    }
}

private TabPage CreateTabPage(String name)
{
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(name);
    tabPage.Enter += new EventHandler(MethodTab_Entered);
    return tabPage;
}

private void MethodTab_Entered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

When I run this code, as far as I can tell, DoSomething() never gets called. I have tried various things such as the Click event, and so on, but cannot get this to work as expected. What am I missing?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: You could try GotFocus event: `tabPage.GotFocus += ...`; or try Selected event of TabControl: `tabControl.Selected += ...` (more info: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Not too sure what goes on on your side, but I can get it to work on my side. When is the first bit of code you pasted actually called ? You show it outside of any method. Please show correct code. Here I put it inside a Button.Click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This here works fine for me:

```
public partial class TabPageForm : Form
{
    private List<string> tabNames;
    public TabPageForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabNames = new List<string>();
        tabNames.Add("NewTab");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool first = true;
        foreach (string tabName in tabNames)
        {
            TabPage tabPage = CreateTabPage(tabName);
            methodTabPage.Controls.Add(tabPage);
            if (first)
            {
                methodTabPage.Select();
                first = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private TabPage CreateTabPage(String name)
    {
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(name);
        tabPage.Enter += new EventHandler(MethodTab_Entered);
        return tabPage;
    }

    private void MethodTab_Entered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

DoSomething is called when I enter the newly created tab.

Of course, the logic of the `first` variable is probably not as you intend it to be, so if you could clarify the semantics of it, I could update my code snippet.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but when you say "when I entered the newly created tab" - do you mean when you were looking at the Ui, and clicked the first tab? Because the case I am concerned with is just when the tabs are being added to the tab control (that is before the user interacts with the UI).

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand your use-case then, cause events will not be fired until the user actually interacts with the UI. On top of that, controls on a TabPage will not be properly inititialized until the TabPage is actually "visited" by the user. What this means, for example, is that data binding will not be functional until the TabPage is visited (or activated I think is the proper word). Maybe if you actually explained what `DoSOmething()` is supposed to be doing, then we could help you with the real solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Essentially, my use case is that I have about thirty "objects" in an array, and I want to display data about each of them on a tab: one tab for each object. In my first version, I simply added the object data to each tab as I created the tab, and added the tab to the tab control. This takes about one minute to do (the DoSomething() method is the object rendering which is quite complicated). I decided to change the code so that only the first object tab is actually rendered, and the other tabs are only rendered when they are clicked. Does this help?